# How do I prevent the Web VisualForce Editor from moving the text up/down when I double clicking?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, chrome

**Scenario:**
When editing VisualForce in the standard Web Interface provided by Salesforce (NOT Dev Console or IDE) within the classic UI via "Setup" in CHROME;

To get there Choose Edit from this page: https://customdomain.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/setup/listApexPage.apexp

When there:
If I DOUBLE CLICK to highlight a line of Text the Text moves up or down to centre (or something like that).
It is extremely annoying, to be honest seems like a bug, or best case it is Chrome reacting differently to how they intended it to function. It does not appear to happen in Firefox. The answer is not to use Firefox, this is not an option.
PE Edition.

**How to prevent it from moving when I double click?**

Answer (score 0):

THIS DID FIX THE ISSUE but caused another issue which was worse (Text was rendering over the top of other text):
THIS highlights the flaw in the Editor that causes the issue.
I just do not know how to fix it with out creating the other issue.

---

I Inspected and Edited this piece of JS:

FROM THIS:

```
onfocus="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=true;"
```

IN

```
<textarea id="textarea" wrap="off" onchange="editArea.execCommand(&quot;onchange&quot;);" onfocus="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=true;" onblur="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=false;" classname="null hidden" class="null hidden" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 15px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; white-space: pre; word-wrap: normal; width: 1688px; height: 1395px;" spellcheck="false">                </textarea>
```

TO THIS:

```
onfocus="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=false;"
```

IN

```
<textarea id="textarea" wrap="off" onchange="editArea.execCommand(&quot;onchange&quot;);" onfocus="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=false;" onblur="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=false;" classname="null hidden" class="null hidden" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 15px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; white-space: pre; word-wrap: normal; width: 1688px; height: 1395px;" spellcheck="false">               </textarea>
```